# Is there a way to retrieve discounts for a product in Craft Commerce v2?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I would like to retrieve all available discounts for an eshop using the Craft Commerce v2.
In Craft Commerce v1, I could use the following:

```
craft.commerce.discounts.all()
```

However, I can't find an equivalent method for Commerce v2

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
craft.commerce.discounts.getAllDiscounts()
```

`craft.commerce.discounts` is a reference to [`services/Discounts`](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/src/services/Discounts.php), so you've got access to all of the public methods in there, of which `getAllDiscounts()` is one.